# Is there a way to use $front_page in node.tpl?

Tags: uri

I'm aware that `$front_page` is a variable used in page.tpl, but is there a way to use it (or something similar other than a direct link) to print the index url in a node.tpl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['front_page'] = url();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. Thank you very much! Do you have any tip on where I can read up on how this works in general?